# How to get the alignment right in this bibliography of biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, koma-script, cv

In the MWE below, I would like to have the references in the bibliography aligned. As you can see the second reference is not aligned with the first reference. I am using the `koma-moderncvclassic` package and its template to generate this CV document. What causes this alignment problem? Your help would be much appreciated.

**MWE**

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{MWE.bib}
@ARTICLE{2006,
  title = {journalarticle},
  journal = {journal},
  year = {2006},
  volume = {6},
  pages = {19--75}
}
@BOOK{2000,
  title = {Some Book},
  address = {Around the Corner},
  year = {2000}
}
\end{filecontents} 

\documentclass[%
fontsize=11pt,%
a4paper,%
pagesize,%
headinclude,footinclude,%
headings=normal,%
]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry} % page layout
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\tolerance=200 % white space
\clubpenalty = 1000 % orphans
\widowpenalty = 1000 % widows

\renewcommand*{\title}{Curriculum Vitae}% für PDF
\newcommand*{\firstname}{John}
\newcommand*{\familyname}{Doe}
\newcommand*{\acadtitle}{MD, PhD}
\newcommand*{\addressstreet}{Street 70}
\newcommand*{\addresscity}{New Avenue}
\newcommand*{\address}[2]{\addressstreet{#1}\addresscity{#2}}
\newcommand*{\mobile}{+999 077777781}
\newcommand*{\email}{anyname (at) domainname.com}

\usepackage[myblue]{koma-moderncvclassic}
\renewcommand{\firstnamefont}{\fontsize{28}{26}\sffamily\mdseries\upshape} % name in smaller font
\newcommand*{\totalpagemark}{\usekomafont{pagenumber}\thepage/\pageref{lastpage}}% for page and pagetotal


\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot
\ifoot{CV~\firstname~\familyname}

\usepackage[backend=biber,%
style=authortitle,% 
sorting=ydnt%
]{biblatex}
\bibliography{MWE.bib}

\defbibheading{bibliography}[Publications]{\section{#1}}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Personal Information}
\cvline{Gender:}{Male}
\cvline{Place of Birth:}{Country}
\cvline{Date of Birith:}{1975}


% \newpage

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\label{lastpage}%

\end{document}

%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% TeX-engine: xetex
%%% End:
```

**Output**

when I compile the document using xetex engine I get this undesired alignment:

[image]

**Desired**

Now if I uncomment the `\newpage` line in the code above I will have the right alignment but I don't want to exceed the one page in my CV. So how to get the alignment right without having a new page in the CV?

[image]

Comment: This is the best question I saw in days! A clear question, shows the desired output and a ready to use MWE which does not require any changes!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a problem caused by the a bug in the `koma-moderncvclassic.sty`.  The real source of the problem  the fact that this package is derived from the `moderncv` class.  Because `moderncv` is a class, it can define macros that are defined in other ways in the standard classes.

### Description of the problem: bug

In the `moderncv` class we find the following definition for `\quote`:

```
\newcommand*{\quote}[1]{\def\@quote{#1}}
```

Of course this has nothing to do with the way the `\quote` (i.e., the beginning of the `quote` *environment*) is defined in `scrartcl`:

```
  \newenvironment{quote}{%
  \list{}{\rightmargin\leftmargin}%
  \item\relax
}{%
  \endlist
}
```

But the code in the package's redefinition of `\maketitle` contains the following:

```
...
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{%
\quote}}%
    {}%
    {\centering{\begin{minipage}{\quotewidth}\centering\quotestyle{\quote}\end{minipage}}%\\[2.5em]
}
```

...

In the original `moderncv` code, the check is for the internally defined `\@quote`, but the author of the package version has incorrectly changed this to the `\quote`.  But since `\quote` is always defined by `scrartcl`, then it executes the second part of the conditional:

```
{\centering{\begin{minipage}{\quotewidth}\centering\quotestyle{\quote}\end{minipage}}
```

This effectively does two things: it places the rest of the document into a `\centering` environment (because the initial `\centering` is not in a group) and it *begins* (but never ends) a `quote` environment.

This is what screws up the indentation of the bibliography: the entire bibliography is inside a list environment (which is the way `quote` is implemented.)

The `\newpage` effectively ends that `quote` environment, which is why the indentation is correct with the new page.

### Solution(s)

Since this is a bug in `koma-moderncvclassic.sty`, a long-term solution would be to get the author to fix it.

#### Quick workaround

A super quick workaround would be to add

```
\let\quote\relax
```

before `\maketitle`. This will prevent the bad piece of code from being executed.  This, of course, will not let you use the `\quote` command from the `moderncv` implementation nor the `quote` environment from `scrartcl`.

#### Fix bug: redefine `\maketitle`

A more robust solution would be to redefine the `\quote` command to match the `moderncv` definition and fix the `maketitle` command of the package.

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\quote[1]{\def\@quote{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\maketitle}{%
  % name and title
  \begin{minipage}[b]{\maketitlenamewidth}%
    \firstnamestyle{%
\firstname~}\familynamestyle{%
\familyname}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{%
\acadtitle}{}}{}{\\[1.25em]\acadtitlestyle{%
\acadtitle}}%
  \end{minipage}%
  % optional data
\begin{minipage}[b]{\maketitledetailswidth}%
    \raggedleft\addressfont\color{addresscolor}%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\addressstreet}}{}{%
      \maketitledetailsnewline%
      \addresssymbol~\addressstreet%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\addresscity}}{}{\\\addresscity}}%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\mobile}}{}{\maketitledetailsnewline\mobilesymbol~\mobile}%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\phone}}{}{\maketitledetailsnewline\phonesymbol~\phone}%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\faxnr}}{}{\maketitledetailsnewline\faxsymbol~\faxnr}%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\email}}{}{\maketitledetailsnewline\emailsymbol~\emaillink{\email}}%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\extrainfo}}{}{\maketitledetailsnewline\extrainfo}%
  \end{minipage}%
% optional photo
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\photoname}}%
    {}%
    {\hspace*{\separatorcolumnwidth}%
     \ifthenelse{\equal{\pictureframe}{noframe}}
      {\begin{minipage}[b]{\photowidth}
         \includegraphics[width=\photowidth]{\photoname}
       \end{minipage}}
      {\color{firstnamecolor}%
       \framebox{\includegraphics[width=\photowidth]{\photoname}}}} 
% optional quote
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{% <---- changed \quote to \@quote below (twice)
\@quote}}%
    {}%
    {{\centering{\begin{minipage}{\quotewidth}\centering\quotestyle{\@quote}\end{minipage}}}%\\[2.5em] <----- added extra pair of braces
}%
}
\makeatother
```

There are some other issues with this package, including the liberal use of `\\[<length>]` where a `\vspace{<length>}` should be used.

### Complete example

Here's a complete example using the workaround (I've added some longer references to show the formatting properly, and used the `showframe` option of `geometry` to show the margins clearly.)

Typically you *do* want bibliography entries to be formatted with a hanging indent, since it makes it easier to separate each one. If you really want the reference to wrap flush with the left margin (which I don't recommend) you can change the length of `\bibhang` to 0.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@book{Knuth1984texbook,
    Author = {Knuth, D.E.},
    Publisher = {Addison-Wesley, Reading, Massachusetts,},
    Title = {The TEXbook, volume A of Computers and typesetting},
    Year = {1984}}


@article{HauserChomskyFitch2002,
    Author = {Hauser, Marc and Chomsky, Noam and Fitch, W. Tecumseh},
    Journal = {Science},
    Number = {5598},
    Pages = {1569--1579},
    Title = {The Faculty of Language: What Is It, Who Has It, and How Did It Evolve?},
    Volume = {298},
    Year = {2002}}
\end{filecontents} 

\documentclass[%
fontsize=11pt,%
a4paper,%
pagesize,%
headinclude,footinclude,%
headings=normal,%
]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm,showframe]{geometry} % page layout
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\tolerance=200 % white space
\clubpenalty = 1000 % orphans
\widowpenalty = 1000 % widows

\renewcommand*{\title}{Curriculum Vitae}% für PDF
\newcommand*{\firstname}{John}
\newcommand*{\familyname}{Doe}
\newcommand*{\acadtitle}{MD, PhD}
\newcommand*{\addressstreet}{Street 70}
\newcommand*{\addresscity}{New Avenue}
\newcommand*{\address}[2]{\addressstreet{#1}\addresscity{#2}}
\newcommand*{\mobile}{+999 077777781}
\newcommand*{\email}{anyname (at) domainname.com}

\usepackage[myblue]{koma-moderncvclassic}
\renewcommand{\firstnamefont}{\fontsize{28}{26}\sffamily\mdseries\upshape} % name in smaller font
\newcommand*{\totalpagemark}{\usekomafont{pagenumber}\thepage/\pageref{lastpage}}% for page and pagetotal
\let\quote\relax% undefine \quote


\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot
\ifoot{CV~\firstname~\familyname}

\usepackage[backend=biber,%
style=authortitle,% 
sorting=ydnt%
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\defbibheading{bibliography}[Publications]{\section{#1}}


\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Personal Information}
\cvline{Gender:}{Male}
\cvline{Place of Birth:}{Country}
\cvline{Date of Birth:}{1975}

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography

\label{lastpage}%

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

If you want the publications list to line up under the left edge of the title, then a redefinition of the `bibliography` environment as in SamCarter's answer can be used. Since I still think the items should have a hanging indent, I would recommend the following redefinition:

```
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
{\list {}
   {\setlength{\leftmargin}{3.6cm}%
    \setlength{\itemindent}{-.4cm}%
    \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
    \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}}
{\endlist}
{\item}
```